# How do I get this function to work with my template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a function that works on another website, but somehow it won't work with this (free) template I am using.

The main js file groups all functions together somehow and just pasting the code in the main.js file gives me a `dropdown is not defined`.

My function:

```
dropdown = function(e){
    var obj = $(e+'.dropdown');
    var btn = obj.find('.btn-selector');
    var dd = obj.find('ul');
    var opt = dd.find('li');

    obj.on("mouseenter", function() {
        dd.show();
    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
        dd.hide();
    })

    opt.on("click", function() {
        dd.hide();
        var txt = $(this).text();
        opt.removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        btn.text(txt);
    });
}
```

Then inside a document ready wrap I call:

```
dropdown('#lang-selector');
```

For the following HTML code:

```
<div id="lang-selector" class="dropdown">
    <a href="index.php?lang=nl" class="btn-selector">NL</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php?lang=en">EN</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?lang=nl">NL</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is a working function in that template:

```
// custom theme
var CustomTheme = function () {

    var _initInstances = function () {
        if ($('.vk-home-dark').length) {
            $('#scrollUp').addClass('inverse');
        }

    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            _initInstances();
        }
    };
}();
```

Which is then called like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    PreLoader.init();
    CustomTheme.init();
    MediaPlayer.init();
});
```

I tried turning `dropdown` to a variable by adding var before it and then calling dropdown.init(); but this gave me `dropdown.init(); is not a function`

How can I make it work like the other functions?

Preloader function as requested:

```
// preloader
var PreLoader = function () {
    var _initInstances = function () {
        $('.animsition').animsition({
            // loadingClass: 'loader',
            inDuration: 900,
            outDuration: 500,
            linkElement: 'a:not([target="_blank"]):not([href^="#"]):not([href^="javascript:void(0);"])',
        });
    };

    return {
        init: function () {
            _initInstances();
        }
    };
}();
```

Comment: can you post `PreLoader` and `MediaPlayer` method code? also I'm not getting `dropdown is not defined`

Comment: @VilasKumkar Ill add the preloader function in my question.